Transferring assets to child
I am a US citizen. I would like to transfer my financial institution account (with all assets) from my name to my adult child’s name. Can I do this and file 709 to show the value as a gift? What are the tax implications for me and for my child?

Yes, you can do this and show it as a gift on your form 709.

What are the tax implications for me and for my child?

For you: you'll need to calculate your gift tax liability. Once you exceed your lifetime exemption (currently about $13.6M), you'll be liable for the gift tax. For details see the form 709 and its instructions.
For your child: they'll get the full value of your gift (the gift tax is your responsibility, not theirs). If you're gifting assets, then you'll need to communicate to them the cost basis, since it is part of the information they'd need to calculated theirs. For example, if you bought a share of company C for $1 10 years ago, and it is now worth $10, you gifted your child an asset valued at $10 with capital gains of $9 if they sell it. So, they'd need to know your cost basis to determine their own tax liability.
The rules for cost basis of gifted property are not entirely trivial, and get even more complicated if gift tax was paid. See the details here.

I strongly advise to discuss this with a tax professional and an estate attorney. There may be much more tax-efficient ways to transfer wealth to children (even if the value of all the assets is below the lifetime exemption).
